# Mongoose index error when connecting with authentication

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to my DB with mongoose and authentication.However, when I do so I get the following error:

```
01-11-2020 08:47:18 error: uncaughtException: Error creating index: command createIndexes requires authentication
Error: Error creating index: command createIndexes requires authentication
```

I have read Mongoose connect tries to create indexes at the beginning if autoIndex option is not set to false. However, I still would like to know why this is failing when authentication is done.

My code is as follows:

```
 const mongooseOptions = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      bufferCommands: false,
      useCreateIndex: true
    };
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      logger.info('Setting DB auth');
      mongooseOptions.user = process.env.MONGO_ROOT_USER;
      mongooseOptions.pass = process.env.MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD;
      mongooseOptions.authSource = 'admin';
    }
    logger.info('Connecting to DB');
    await mongoose.connect(databaseURL, mongooseOptions); // error comes from this call
    logger.info('Connected to DB');
```

Is this a bug? I have taken a quick look inside mongoose code and presumably it should connect before creating indexes as far as I see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Comment: Does your user have the proper grants/roles to create indexes on your database?

Comment: Yes, because I am using the root user to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the code I posted was ok. Problem was I had elsewhere a MongoDBStore session which implicitly connects to the DB as well behind the scene and that was the one triggering the error as I was not passing to MongoDBStore the auth values.